# Method return type in C++

Tags: c++

I was reading some code for some project I had to complete as an assignment. But I didn't get the syntax.

```
ClassTable::ClassTable(Classes classes) : semant_errors(0) , error_stream(cerr) {

/* some code here */
// if there are errors, it calls semant_error() , which is another method in ClassTable class and returns

return;
```

What I don't get is what does it mean to use : in a method definition ( like : semant_error()) and anothe problem I have is that this method should return ClassTable object(?) , but it's like is not returning anything.

sorry for the dump questions, I'm not familiar with C++.

Comment: This is a constructor for the class `ClassTable` in case this is unclear.

Comment: And you might need to study more about the basics of C++ classes and how their constructors work. [Here's a list of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), please invest in a couple.